# When number of char in textbox is reached, jump to button to Enter

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox in a Windows Form. (C#)
In that textbox the user can enter 9 char.
After entering the char, the user hase to go to a button and click.

Is there a possibility, when the 9 char are reached, there is a automatic selection of the button, so that the user has only to tap Enter en the next step of the program can start ?

Excuses for my English. :-)

Comment: your algorithm should be based on the "KeyUp" event, check the input size for each event. When the limit is reached, change the "focus" to the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if (txtBox.Text.Length == 9)
{
   btnEnter.Focus();
}
```

this will focus on the btnEnter if character is equal to 9, you might add additional validation to block user input if it will be more than 9 or change the logic to `txtBox.Text.Length >= 9`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Gabriel's solution would be to hook the `KeyUp` event, check if the return key has been pressed, and initiate a button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do whatever
}

private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return && textBox1.Text.Length == 6) // check if key is return and textbox length is 6
    {
        button1.PerformClick(); // perform a button click
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to set the [AcceptButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton?view=netcore-3.1) property of the FORM to your Button.  This causes it to be pressed when the Enter key is pressed, even when it is not focused.  Then you set its initial state to disabled, and only enable it when there are 9 chars in your TextBox.  So the user will enter the value and simply hit Enter, the Button will not need to have focus:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Enabled = false;
        this.AcceptButton = button1;
        textBox1.MaxLength = 9;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = (textBox1.TextLength == 9);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("7...8...9");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I called my void TextBox_Changed.
I linked it in the textbox Properties to TextChanged.

Thanks for the quick answers.